# How to access multiple trees' items in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, angular-material, indexof

I am using Angular mat-tree in a project as a filter for a table.
I created 3 different nested trees with checkboxes ([image of the trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG0fY.png)).

I generated these trees using backend data and creating a service in my frontend (with Spring and Angular 8) as shown below.

Now, I want to access each item of the 3 trees using this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node), but the problem is that dataNodes only stores the latest created tree (here "Scenarios" tree). So when i use this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node) for another tree, it says : indexOf(node) = -1

I wonder if there is a way to access all those trees' items by index. 
I would also need to access all items with level 0 if possible.

I share a stackblitz demo, which is a simplified version of my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvbg5j

```
export class FiltersDatabase {
  [x: string]: any;

  dataChangeSub = new BehaviorSubject<TodoItemNode[]>([]);
  dataChangeSce = new BehaviorSubject<TodoItemNode[]>([]);
  dataChangeAlg = new BehaviorSubject<TodoItemNode[]>([]);

  subjectsTypes : SubjectType[];
  scenarios: Scenario[];
  algorithms: Algorithm[];


  get dataSub(): TodoItemNode[] { return this.dataChangeSub.value; }
  get dataSce(): TodoItemNode[] { return this.dataChangeSce.value; }
  get dataAlg(): TodoItemNode[] { return this.dataChangeAlg.value; }

  constructor(private scenarioService : ScenarioService, private protocolService: ProtocolService) {
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    // Build the tree nodes from Json object. The result is a list of `TodoItemNode` with nested
    //     file node as children.

    //creating the subjects filter
    this.protocolService.getSubjectTypes().
    subscribe(response => {
      this.subjectsTypes = response;

      let namesSub : any = [];

      this.subjectsTypes.forEach(elem =>{
        let namesSub_node: string = elem.name;
        namesSub.push(namesSub_node);
      });
      let root_objSub: any = {
        "Subjects" : namesSub
      }
      const dataSub = this.buildFileTree(root_objSub, 0);
      this.dataChangeSub.next(dataSub);
    });


    //creating the PIs filter
    this.protocolService.getAlgorithms()
    .subscribe(response =>{
      this.algorithms = response;

      let namesAlg : any = [];

      this.algorithms.forEach(elem =>{
        let namesAlg_node: string = elem.name;
        namesAlg.push(namesAlg_node);
      });
      let root_objAlg: any = {
        "Algorithms" : namesAlg
      }
      const dataAlg = this.buildFileTree(root_objAlg, 0);
      this.dataChangeAlg.next(dataAlg);
    });

    //creating the Scenarios filter
    this.scenarioService.getScenarios()
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.scenarios =response;

      let tree_Sce: any = []; // this will be array of objects
      // collect all the descriptions and names nodes form the data array
      let idSce: any= [];
      let namesSce:any = [];

      this.scenarios.forEach(elem => {

        let idSce_node: number = elem.scenario_id
        idSce.push(idSce_node);

        let namesSce_node: string= elem.name
        namesSce.push(namesSce_node);
      });

      let root_objSce: any = {
        "Scenarios" : {
          "ID": idSce,
          "Names" : namesSce
        }
      };
      tree_Sce.push(root_objSce);

      const dataSce = this.buildFileTree(root_objSce, 0);
      this.dataChangeSce.next(dataSce);
    });


  }

  /**
  * Build the file structure tree. The `value` is the Json object, or a sub-tree of a Json object.
  * The return value is the list of `TodoItemNode`.
  */
  buildFileTree(obj: {[key: string]: any}, level: number): TodoItemNode[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce<TodoItemNode[]>((accumulator, key) => {
      const value = obj[key];
      const node = new TodoItemNode();
      node.item = key;

      if (value != null) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          node.children = this.buildFileTree(value, level + 1);
        } else {
          node.item = value;
        }
      }

      return accumulator.concat(node);
    }, []);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/ .

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, because I use backend data...

Comment: you can create a dummy json data of backend response

Comment: okay, i am trying, thanks

Comment: @ShashankVivek, I edited the question with the stackblitz link. We can see in the console when we select an item from tree2 (last created) that it works fine (index of 1,2 or whatever) but when you try the same on tree1, you have an index of -1 (means that the array doesn't exist or so)

Comment: the function I use is getParentNode

Comment: I found the solution asking another question, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58725906/how-to-access-data-from-2-different-mat-tree-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment103744567_58725906

Comment: Apologies for my late reply. Thanks