# How to access data from 2 different mat-tree in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, angular-material

in my project, I am using 2 different trees from angular material.

I created a demo on stackblitz here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvbg5j.

When I try to access their data, I use treeControl.dataNodes but it only gives me the data from the latest generated tree ("groceries2 and reminders2 tree). It displays dataNodes in the console each time I check/uncheck an item.

So I don't know what to do, is there another way to access tree data? or is there a function that stores both trees in memory?

Comment: Hi, what about dataSource.data

Comment: Oh yeah ... it works @Z.Bolbol . Sorry, I'm quite new to this. 

It gives me the tree as "TodoItemNode" , and I would lilke to have it as an array of "TodoItemFlatNode" (like it does with treeControl.dataNodes). I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: just use two tree control in this case, one for each tree

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try this

Comment: It works as i wanted it with two treeControl

Comment: glad to know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the data source as an argument when you handle the checkbox change :

```
(change)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node, dataSourceX)"
```

And inside your function just access to the data attribute :

```
todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode, dataSource : MatTreeFlatDataSource<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>): void {
    console.log(dataSource.data) ;
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
    this.getParentNode(node)
  }
```